# saving manipulated values in CoreData causing error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity named `Record` in `core-data`. The problem is that I could not save the object after manipulation as follows:

```
extension Records {
@nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Records> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Records>(entityName: "Records")
}

@NSManaged public var datetime: Date
@NSManaged public var year: Int64
@NSManaged public var month: Int16

public override func willSave() {
    super.willSave()

    if (self.datetime != nil) {

        self.year = Int64(datetime.year())
        self.month = Int16(datetime.month())
    }
}
}

extension Date {
    func month() -> Int {
        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
        return month
    }

    func year() -> Int {
        let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
        return year
    }
}
```

This is the error message I have faced:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 1000 attempts.  Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506209-willsave):

> If you want to update a persistent property value, you should
>   typically test for equality of any new value with the existing value
>   before making a change. **If you change property values using standard
>   accessor methods, Core Data will observe the resultant change
>   notification and so invoke willSave again before saving the object’s
>   managed object context**. If you continue to modify a value in willSave,
>   willSave will continue to be called until your program crashes.

So in case of `wilSave` method, recheck while saving `self.year` & `self.month` needed to be assigned or not. Otherwise assigning them the value without checking will let `willSave` called again.

```
//your code
public override func willSave() {
    super.willSave()

        guard let dettime = datetime else {
            return
        }

        if self.year != Int64(datetime.year()) {
            self.year = Int64(datetime.year())
        }

        if self.month != Int64(datetime.month()) {
            self.month = Int16(datetime.month())
        }
    }
// your code
```

Comment: This code causes error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int64' with an argument list of type '(() -> Int)'

Comment: this is just type conversion error, i've just copied it over from your code. i just added extra checking over your code so that the `willSave` won't called over and over again.